# How can I set a specific option on a select form, when its created dynamically in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

How can I set a specific option on a select form, when its created dynamically in Angular 2 ?

Sample typeModel.type = type: 'Red Cars'

contactTypes is an array of types, type: 'Red Cars' and 'Blue Cars'

```
<select class="form-control" name="type" [(ngModel)]="typeModel.type"> 
    <option *ngFor="let contactType of contactTypes">
        {{contactType.type}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add values to `<option>` elements by setting the **`[value]`** property, like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="type" [(ngModel)]="typeModel.type"> 
    <option *ngFor="let contactType of contactTypes" [value]="contactType.type">
        {{contactType.type}}
    </option>
</select>
```

(Here's the working solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/JNzyHRHQXxYAWNTcAdT7)